# EF6 doesn't select two-deep ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three classes in EF that are basically setup as follows (extraneous fields omitted):

```
public class TopLevel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TopLevelId { get; set; }

    public Guid MidLevelId { get; set; }
    public virtual MidLevel { get; set; }
}

public class MidLevel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MidLevelId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LowLevel> LowLevels { get; set; }
}

public class LowLevel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid LowLevelId { get; set; }

    public Guid MidLevelId { get; set; }
}
```

I have generated my tables using this code and have correctly inserted records into the tables according to my expectations -- one TopLevel, one MidLevel associated with the TopLevel and one LowLevel associated with the MidLevel. When I do a query against my TopLevel table, eg:

```
var top = context.TopLevels.First(topLevel => topLevel.TopLevelId == someTopLevelId);
```

Both the `TopLevel` item queried and its virtual `MidLevel` member are retrieved, but the MidLevel item's collection of `LowLevel` items is empty. The database *does* contain the record, but it's not retrieved.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with my annotations? Do I need to do a `.Include()` or something similar?

**Edit**: I'm querying my top-level like this:

```
var top = context.TopLevels.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TopLevelId == myTopGuid);
```

I also try directly querying the mid-level as follows:

```
Guid midId = (value from database here);
var mid = context.MidLevels.First(m => m.MidLevelId == midId);
```

In both cases, top.MidLevel.LowLevels or mid.LowLevels has a `.Count == 0`.

Comment: You didn't define any foreign keys.

Comment: Can you show the code where you access `top`?

Comment: @Rob: I've tried adding FKs but get `Add-Migration` messages like `The property 'MidLevelId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. ...`. I have another pair of classes in which I use `[ForeignKey]`, and that works as expected.

@YacoubMassad: Updated post to include my code for accessing `top`.

Comment: Try adding `.Include(x => MidLevel.LowLevels)`. Its a little strange if this works, since you did put `virtual` into your code. However I usual disable lazy loading because it causes more performance problems than it is worth, by hiding poor programming practices.

Comment: Apart from your problem it seems that `MidLevel`actually is the top level having a one to many relation with both `TopLevel` and `LowLevel`.

Comment: @user655321 You've configured it incorrectly if you get that error. For example, you need to add `public virtual MidLevel MidLevel { get; set; }` and then add the attribute on `MidLevelId` as `[ForeignKey("MidLevel")]` on your `LowLevel` class.

Comment: @Rob: I have `public virtual MidLevel MidLevel { get; set; }` and `[ForeignKey("MidLevel")] public Guid MidLevelId { get; set; }` in `LowLevel`. SQL Server Management Studio confirms that my `LowLevel` table has `MidLevelId (FK, uniqueidentifier, not null)` on it. However, the collection is still empty upon accessing my top-level class.